# Having bugs in digPow function "expected -1 to equal 12933"

Tags: javascript

**Hello I want to ask what's wrong with my solution when I am gonna test the solution it appears that expected -1 to equal 12933**
The whole instructions are from [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5552101f47fc5178b1000050/train/javascript)

**The Question:**
Some numbers have funny properties. For example:

89 --> 8¹ + 9² = 89 * 1

695 --> 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2

46288 --> 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51

Given a positive integer n written as abcd... (a, b, c, d... being digits) and a positive integer p

we want to find a positive integer k, if it exists, such that the sum of the digits of n taken to the successive powers of p is equal to k * n.
In other words:

Is there an integer k such as : (a ^ p + b ^ (p+1) + c ^(p+2) + d ^ (p+3) + ...) = n * k

If it is the case we will return k, if not return -1.

Note: n and p will always be given as strictly positive integers.

```
digPow(89, 1) should return 1 since 8¹ + 9² = 89 = 89 * 1
digPow(92, 1) should return -1 since there is no k such as 9¹ + 2² equals 92 * k
digPow(695, 2) should return 2 since 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2
digPow(46288, 3) should return 51 since 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51
```

**My Solution:**

```
function digPow(p, n) { 
  let arrayP = [...String(p)].map((e) => Number(e));
  let arrayPLength = arrayP.length;
  let nums = [];
  let firstResult = [];

  for (let i = n; i < 5000; i++) {
    nums.push(i);
  }

  for (let i = n; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let currentPow = [];
    let j = i;
    let k = i + arrayPLength;
    while (j < k) {
      currentPow.push(j);
      j++;
      if (j == k) break;
    }
    let result = 0;
    for (let h = 0; h < arrayP.length; h++) {
      result = arrayP[h] ** currentPow[h] + result;
    }
    firstResult.push(result);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < firstResult.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      if (firstResult[i] == p * j) return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, it is not `digPow(p, n)` but `digPow(n, p)` the order matters. It's not the same `digPow(89, 1)` than `digPow(1, 89)`. "n taken to the successive powers of p".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some problems in your code, the main one was a *nested for loop*.

```
for (let i = n; i < nums.length; i++) {
...
    for (let h = 0; h < arrayP.length; h++) {
```

Here is your code with some fixes:

```
function digPow(p, n) {    
  let arrayP = [...String(p)].map((e) => Number(e));
  let arrayPLength = arrayP.length; // is this variable necessary?
  let nums = [];
  let firstResult = [];

  for (let i = n; i < 5000; i++) {
    nums.push(i);
  }

  let currentPow = []; // Make this variable available outside the for loop scope
  for (let i = n; i < nums.length; i++) {    
    let j = i;
    let k = i + arrayP.length;
    while (j < k) {
      currentPow.push(j);
      j++;
      // I removed the unncessary if (j == k) break; 
    }
  } // This for loop should end here
  let result = 0;
  for (let h = 0; h < arrayP.length; h++) {
    result = arrayP[h] ** currentPow[h] + result;
  }  
  
  // No more need of those two for loops you had
  // You now can simply test:
  if (result % p == 0) {
    return result / p;
  }
```

I tried your code with those fixes and now all tests are passing.

Here is another option to solve this with `reduce` using the syntax with the `currentIndex`

`reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => { /* … */ })`:

```
function digPow(n, p) {  
  const digits = [...String(n)].map((e) => Number(e));  
  const result = digits.reduce((acc, d, i) => { 
    acc += d ** (p+i);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
  return (result % n == 0) ? result / n : -1;
}
```